# Rsync filters in a python loop

Tags: python, ftp, subprocess, rsync

After reading the man page on filtering rules and looking here:  [Using Rsync filter to include/exclude files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35364075/using-rsync-filter-to-include-exclude-files)

I don't understand why the code below doesn't work.

```
import subprocess, os
from ftplib import FTP

ftp_site = 'ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov'
ftp = FTP(ftp_site)
ftp.login()
ftp.cwd('genomes/genbank/bacteria')
dirs = ftp.nlst()

for organism in dirs:
    latest = os.path.join(organism, "latest_assembly_versions")
    for path in ftp.nlst(latest):
        accession = path.split("/")[-1]
        fasta = accession+"_genomic.fna.gz"
        subprocess.call(['rsync',
                         '--recursive',
                         '--copy-links',
                         #'--dry-run',
                         '-vv',
                         '-f=+ '+accession+'/*',
                         '-f=+ '+fasta,
                         '-f=- *',
                         'ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov::genomes/genbank/bacteria/'+latest,
                         '--log-file=scratch/test_dir/log.txt',
                         'scratch/' + organism])
```

I also tried `'--exclude=*[^'+fasta+']'` to try to exclude files that don't match `fasta` instead of `-f=- *`

For each directory `path` within `latest/*`, I want the file that matches  `fasta` exactly.  There will always be exactly one file `fasta` in the directory `latest/path`.

**EDIT:**  I am testing this with **rsync version 3.1.0** and have seen incompatibility issues with earlier versions.

Here is a link to working code that you should be able to paste into a python interpreter to get the results of a "dry run," which won't download anything onto your machine:  http://pastebin.com/0reVKMCg  it gets EVERYTHING under `ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov::genomes/genbank/bacteria/'+latest`, which is not what I want. and if I run that script with `'-f=- *'` uncommented, it doesn't get anything, which seems to contradict the answer here [Using Rsync filter to include/exclude files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35364075/using-rsync-filter-to-include-exclude-files)

Comment: Are you sure that you can use `rsync` over FTP?: http://serverfault.com/questions/24622/how-to-use-rsync-over-ftp

Comment: Yes, I am sure.  I had a similar script working beautifully until I realized that some of the files I was getting (according to my filters) were files that I didn't want.

Comment: hmm, could you post the working snippet so that we can get an example output and then further elucidate what you are trying to filter?

Comment: Absolutely - thanks for asking!  This http://pastebin.com/0reVKMCg works, but it looks like it gets EVERYTHING under `ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov::genomes/genbank/bacteria/'+latest`.  and if I run that script with `'-f=- *'` uncommented, it doesn't get anything, which seems to contradict the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35364075/using-rsync-filter-to-include-exclude-files

Comment: running that pastebin didn't produce anything for me...

Comment: It literally didn't produce _anything_?  No errors, no nothing?  Please see my edit.  I am using rsync version 3.1.0 which may be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This part of the rsync man page contained the info I needed to solve my problem:

> Note  that,  when  using the --recursive (-r) option (which is implied by -a), every subcomponent of every
> path is visited from the top down, so include/exclude patterns get applied recursively to  each  subcompo-
> nent's  full  name  (e.g.  to  include  "/foo/bar/baz" the subcomponents "/foo" and "/foo/bar" must not be
> excluded).  The exclude patterns actually short-circuit the directory traversal stage when rsync finds the
> files  to  send.  If a pattern excludes a particular parent directory, it can render a deeper include pat-
> tern ineffectual because rsync did not descend through that excluded section of the  hierarchy.   This  is
> particularly important when using a trailing '*' rule.  For instance, this won't work:
>
> + /some/path/this-file-will-not-be-found
>
> + /file-is-included
>
> - *
>
> This  fails  because the parent directory "some" is excluded by the '*' rule, so rsync never visits any of
> the files in the "some" or "some/path" directories.  One solution is to ask for  all  directories  in  the
> hierarchy to be included by using a single rule: "+ */" (put it somewhere before the "- *" rule), and per-
> haps use the --prune-empty-dirs option.  Another solution is to add specific include  rules  for  all  the
> parent dirs that need to be visited.  For instance, this set of rules works fine:
>
> + /some/
>
> + /some/path/
>
> + /some/path/this-file-is-found
>
> + /file-also-included
>
> - *

This helped me write the following code:

```
def get_fastas(local_mirror="scratch/ncbi", bacteria="Escherichia_coli"):
        ftp_site = 'ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov'
        ftp = FTP(ftp_site)
        ftp.login()
        ftp.cwd('genomes/genbank/bacteria')
        rsync_log = os.path.join(local_mirror, "rsync_log.txt")
        latest = os.path.join(bacteria, 'latest_assembly_versions')
        for parent in ftp.nlst(latest)[0:2]:
                accession = parent.split("/")[-1]
                fasta = accession+"_genomic.fna.gz"
                organism_dir = os.path.join(local_mirror, bacteria)
                subprocess.call(['rsync',
                                '--copy-links',
                                '--recursive',
                                '--itemize-changes',
                                '--prune-empty-dirs',
                                '-f=+ '+accession,
                                '-f=+ '+fasta,
                                '--exclude=*',
                                'ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov::genomes/genbank/bacteria/'+parent,
                                organism_dir])
```

It turns out `'-f=+ '+accession,` doesn't work with a `*` after the trailing `/`.  Although it does work with just a trailing `/` without the `*`