# Bash rsync script to recursively copy video & dir structure from FUSE?

Tags: bash, rsync, fuse

I am trying to copy all video files recursively from a locally synced FUSE file system (GDrive, Insync, Cryptomator, Ubuntu 20.04), recreating the source directory structure in the destination for any video that is moved - only. Although it is working for some video others are left behind with the same file extension as some that were successfully moved.

Can I adjust my script somehow to make this work properly please? I was also using --ignore-existing but I removed it and have been testing with an empty source directory just in case that helped but it did not.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define source and destination directories
src_dir="/home/user/cloud"
dest_dir="/home/user/testmove"

# Use rsync to move files and create directories recursively

rsync --progress --ignore-existing -avm -f'+ *[mM][pP]3$' -f'+ *[fF][lL][aA][cC]$' -f'+ *[mM][4][aA]$' -f'+ *[wW][aA][vV]$' -f'+ *[aA][iI][fF][fF]$' -f'+ *[pP][cC][mM]$' -f'+ *[aA][aA][cC]$' -f'+ *[oO][gG][gG]$' -f'+ *[aA][lL][aA][cC]$' -f'+ */' -f'- *' "$src_dir"/ "$dest_dir"/ --prune-empty-dirs
```

I found using the $ stopped any files being copied but I am testing following which seems to work, and Eric's much more comprehensive and flexible version from his answer below:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define source and destination directories
src_dir="/home/user/cloud"
dest_dir="/home/user/testmove"

# Use rsync to copy files and create directories recursively
rsync -ahPv \
-f'+ *.[mM][pP]3' \
-f'+ *.[mM][4][aA]' \
-f'+ *.[wW][aA][vV]' \
-f'+ *.[oO][gG][gG]' \
-f'+ *.[wW][mM][aA]' \
-f'+ *.[fF][lL][aA][cC]' \
-f'+ *.[aA][iI][fF][fF]' \
-f'+ *.[pP][cC][mM]' \
-f'+ *.[aA][aA][cC]' \
-f'+ *.[aA][lL][aA][cC]' \
-f'+ */' \
-f'- *' \
"$src_dir"/ "$dest_dir"  --prune-empty-dirs --stats -n

# To delete empty directories left in source when transferring:
# find "$src_dir" -depth -type d -empty -delete
```

Comment: That "--remove-source-files" option is VERY destructive unless you know what you are doing.  The code segment ... "**-f'- \*' **" ... is leaving those files behind for some reason because they were not matched by the other match specifications.  I also find it curious that you don't include the "$" to match end of string, or the "." to match the start of the suffix.  Maybe define the opposite logic, to see what is being matched when it should not.

Comment: You would benefit from looking at the first Answer in detail [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35364075/using-rsync-filter-to-include-exclude-files) .

Comment: All good advice, thanks. I am now using a backed up source, dry runs, and copy not transfer only. Introducing the $ with/without the . seemed to not help, at least in how I was testing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some elements of the command structure which were conflicting, preventing the desired restrictions, and overlooking the inclusions.  The following form provides the desired output.

Note that I have some hardcoded values that you need to remove.

```
#!/bin/bash

audio=1
video=0
DryRun=""

while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    case $1 in
        --source ) src_dir="$2" ; shift ; shift ;;
        --target ) dest_dir="$2" ; shift ; shift ;;
        --audio ) audio=1 ; video=0 ; shift ;;
        --video ) audio=0 ; video=1 ; shift ;;
        --dry ) DryRun="--dry-run --stats" ; shift ;;
        * ) echo -e "\n Invalid option used on command line.  Only valid options: [ --source {src_dir} | --target {dest_dir} | --audio | --video | --dry ]\n Bye!\n" ; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done

# Define source and destination directories
#src_dir="/home/user/cloud"
src_dir="`pwd`/Output"
#dest_dir="/home/user/testmove"
dest_dir="`pwd`/Dupl"

# Define rules for include or exclude
cat >"EXCLUDES.filters" <<"EnDoFiNpUt"
- *
EnDoFiNpUt

#filters="--filter \"merge AUDIO_TYPES.filters\" "      ### THIS FORM DOES NOT WORK !!!

if [ ${audio} -eq 1 ]
then
    ### NOTE:  Trailing "$" to match end of string is implicit, unless there is a trailing "*"
    cat >"AUDIO_TYPES.filters" <<"EnDoFiNpUt"
+ */
+ *\.[mM][pP][3]
+ *\.[fF][lL][aA][cC]
+ *\.[mM][4][aA]
+ *\.[wW][aA][vV]
+ *\.[aA][iI][fF][fF]
+ *\.[pP][cC][mM]
+ *\.[aA][aA][cC]
+ *\.[oO][gG][gG]
+ *\.[aA][lL][aA][cC]
EnDoFiNpUt

    filters="--include-from=AUDIO_TYPES.filters --exclude-from=EXCLUDES.filters"
fi

if [ ${video} -eq 1 ]
then
    ### NOTE:  Trailing "$" to match end of string is implicit, unless there is a trailing "*"
    cat >"VIDEO_TYPES.filters" <<"EnDoFiNpUt"
+ */
+ *\.[mM][pP][4]
+ *\.[aA][vV][iI]
+ *\.[mM][kK][vV]
+ *\.[fF][lL][vV]
+ *\.[wW][mM][vV]
+ *\.[mM][oO][vV]
+ *\.[Aa][Vv][Cc][Hh][Dd]
+ *\.[wW][eE][bB][mM]
+ *\.[hH][2][6][4]
+ *\.[mM][pP][eE][gG][4]
+ *\.[Aa][Vv][Cc][Hh][Dd]
EnDoFiNpUt

    filters="--include-from=VIDEO_TYPES.filters --exclude-from=EXCLUDES.filters"
fi

# Use rsync to move files and create directories recursively

### NOTE: I prefer long-form options for understanding code at first glance; shortform doesn't do that for me.
#rsync  -rlptgoDvP          ### shortform for universal options
rsync   \
    --verbose \
    --recursive \
    --links \
    --owner \
    --group \
    --perms \
    --times \
    --devices \
    --specials \
    --prune-empty-dirs \
    --partial \
    --progress \
    ${DryRun}\
    ${filters} \
    "${src_dir}/" "${dest_dir}/"
```

Log of session output:

```
building file list ... 
3 files to consider
created directory /0__WORK/Dupl
./
DEF.mP4
              0 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=1/3)
abc.mp4
              0 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#2, to-chk=0/3)

sent 196 bytes  received 126 bytes  644.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

Session log for version of script modified per requestor's (saltyeggs) reformulated command (also works, differently, but as expected):

```
building file list ... 
3 files to consider
created directory /0__WORK/Dupl
./
DEF.mP4
abc.mp4

Number of files: 3 (reg: 2, dir: 1)
Number of created files: 3 (reg: 2, dir: 1)
Number of deleted files: 0
Number of regular files transferred: 2
Total file size: 0 bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 0
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 128
Total bytes received: 94

sent 128 bytes  received 94 bytes  444.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
```

Comment: Thank you Eric for this very complete answer, I was in fact also planning to use it for video. I updated my question to include an edit of my original code but I do appreciate the extra options and loop use in yours, still to finish testing both.

Comment: I edited both sets of source and destination, and the command slightly to dry-run and output stats and remove the prune argument as -m covers that, and added -P for progress and partial: ```rsync   -avmnP \
 --stats \
    ${filters} \
    "${src_dir}/" "${dest_dir}/"```

Unfortunately this results in 0 transfers. Is it working for you or did I miss something?

Comment: My test script fully replicated the situation, by creating dummy files in the src_dir and only those were recognized and moved, assuming that was what you wanted. So ... yes, it did work for me, as the session log demonstrated. I modified the command as per your comment, and it still provides what I though you would expect. See second session log. NOTE:  "**DRY RUN**" says that it will only tell what would happen, **not actually perform the action**.